# How to tell bundler to ignore gems that don't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

My organization has a number of in-house gems that are used in automated testing, but are not required for a production deployment. I am trying to use Bundler and so in my Gemfile I've wrapped those gems in:

```
group :test, :development do
    gem 'dashboard_summary'
end
```

However, when I run:

```
$ bundle install --without staging development test
```

I still get

```
Could not find gem 'dashboard_summary (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

I'm trying to understand why Bundler isn't ignoring that gem when I've told it to.

Comment: Post your `Gemfile`. `dashboard_summary` might be a dependency for some other gem

Comment: How are you specifying the `dashboard_summary` gem? Do you have multiple `source` lines, if so how are you avoiding errors from your internal repository not being available in production?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. From [the docs](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/man/bundle-install.1.html#INSTALLING-GROUPS):

> While the `--without` option will skip *installing* the gems in the specified groups, it will still *download* those gems and use them to resolve the dependencies of every gem in your Gemfile(5).

Whilst an up to date `Gemfile.lock` might suggest that the dependencies don’t need to be resolved again, it looks like all gems are downloaded even in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure what the distinction between 'installing' and 'downloading' is. I thought ruby was interpreted.

Does bundler have a feature that will achieve my goal (i.e. completely ignoring certain gems in production?)

Comment: Installing will extract the downloaded gem package into appropriate place and compile C-extensions if necessary. This way it is in `gem list` and you can `require` it.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't define any group that includes staging, development and test. Your group only had test and development.

Bundler is trying to ignore a group which has all three name in it, so you can add staging to

```
group :test, :development, :staging do
    gem 'dashboard_summary'
end
```

or you can use

```
 $ bundle install --without test development
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you have `staging` in there? but this should work

```
 bundle install --without test development
```

You could also set the config environment variable documented in `BUNDLE_WITHOUT` in [bundle config](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/bundle_config.html).

You could use

```
gem 'dashboard_summary', require: false
```

This would not load the gem on startup and you would have to require it when you wanted to use the gem. This may help if you need to keep `dashboard_summary` in your Gemfile because of dependencies, but save the time it takes to load and not get the error you are getting now. It's at least something to try.

Comment: It looks like `dashboard_summary` is a dependency for other gem(s). In that case, you can't ignore it.