# Can I get rubygems to ignore gem version conflicts?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies

I have done a bit of digging through the rubygems code and it doesn't look like there is a built-in way to get it to not throw a `Gem::ConflictError` even if there is one.  During development I might be wanting to test something that I know is not going to touch the code from which the conflict is coming or I know that the whatever version of the erstwhile conflicting gem isn't going to cause a problem.  I just want to get on with testing what I want to test and I'll worry about version conflicts later.

I know I can hack rubygems to do this.  I can think or multiple ways to get it done.  I'm just kind of curious if anyone has already done this, how they did it, and maybe if that code has been shared somewhere.  I'm also a bit curious as to why this isn't built in to rubygems as a development tool.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741935/how-to-tell-bundler-to-ignore-gems-that-dont-exist#16742178) helps you, using a `require: false` parameter for each gem in the Gemfile.

Answer (score 2):

You need to worry about version conflicts now before you can get anything done. As Ruby has a singular root namespace and every dependency gets loaded there it's generally not possible to load multiple versions of the same gem. Other systems like NPM for Node.js are significantly more flexible, it's possible to load any number of versions at the same time, so if you're used to that you'll need to adjust your expectations.

If you're trying to do testing and you want to avoid resolving a conflict, just remove that `gem` requirement from the `Gemfile` temporarily.

Ultimately you'll have to fix things, there's no way around it, but you can always be selective about what you require.

Comment: Agreed. It's better to determine where the conflict is up front, before writing a lot of code based on bad assumptions, that locks things into place and makes it even more difficult to backtrack.

Comment: It is entirely possible to load multiple versions of code.  The fact that rubygems is trying to manage that is ancillary and not intrinsic to Ruby.  It is perhaps inadvisable in some situations, but not at all difficult to do. I tried to imply that ultimately, yes, conflicts need to be resolved (hence the "During development..."). The point is that sometimes you have stuff in your head that you want to deal with **right now** and having to forget all that and fix a conflict that you **know** is not going to be in play **right now** is just counter-productive.  So, I disagree here.

Comment: First of all, just because it can be *theoretically* done doesn't mean it's actually practical to do. A properly coded gem may survive being renamed. Many won't because they assume they have control over their designated namespace(s). If two different versions of a gem are loaded simultaneously you will have conflict and it can get messy as the constant friction between the YAML parser bundled with Ruby core and the gem version shows again and again. This is a super thorny problem in the Ruby world.

Comment: If you want to get things done, which is perfectly understandable, start disabling dependencies and do what you have to do.  If you can come up with an elegant solution for side-loading alternate versions of a Ruby gem, perhaps using the new "Refinements" feature, I'm sure other people would be interested in how you did it. I've never seen a good general purpose solution. Every time I've had to do it I forked the gem, renamed things, and tested it exhaustively before loading it back in.

Comment: We routinely (every day) load and run code that is alternative to the code found in a given gemset.  That isn't really a challenge at all.  Getting the dependencies ignored is the challenge.  One way to load alternative code is to just unshift the desired path to your code onto the load path.  Another thing you can do is to go into your gems dir and replace the gem with a symlink to your code in progress.  We usually opt for the former but the latter is sometimes necessary (e.g. when we are working on JRuby plugins for 3rd party software).

Comment: You can always use the `path:` option in `Gemfile` which will allow you to work on local copies of the gem until you resolve conflicts. You can't have two contradictory versions of a gem loaded if they both use the same namespace.

Answer (score 1):

If you really know what you are doing, try this:

```
export NOEXEC_DISABLE=1
ruby you-program.rb
```

This environment variable will disable search and check for Gemfiles and gem versions.

Comment: A bit heavy-handed...but I like it!  I'll give it a try next time I am in need.